# ogr2ogr Batchfile from TSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr

I have a stored procedure with the following sql

```
EXECUTE xp_CMDShell 
'\\gissrv\data\BroadSpectrumSQLTreeExtract\ogr2ogr_reproject.bat'
```

which is meant to run the batch file containing

```
pushd \\gissrv\data\BroadSpectrumSQLTreeExtract\ogr2ogr

ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" 
"MSSQL:server=gissrv;database=Infrastructure;trusted_connection=yes" 
"MSSQL:server=gissrv;database=Infrastructure;trusted_connection=yes" -sql 
"SELECT * FROM [Infrastructure].[dbo].[BS_Trees_Line_Shire_Inv]" -t_srs 
"EPSG:28355" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=geometry" -lco "GEOM_NAME=GEOMETRY_SPA" -nln 
"BS_Trees_Line_Shire_Inv_reprojected2"

popd \\gissrv\data\BroadSpectrumSQLTreeExtract\ogr2ogr
```

The pushd creates a temporary Z drive to access the ogr2ogr.exe, then reprojects SQL data into a new table. It works when I run it, but fails with from SQL. I get the following.

```
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: 
Z:\BroadSpectrumSQLTreeExtract\ogr2ogr\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have given the folder SQL Service permissions (full control). I also tried giving permissions in the batch file. xp_CMDShell has also been configured on the server. Can you run such a script from SQL Server?

Comment: Is bat file on your SQL Server or local machine?

Comment: The bat file is on the same server as the SQL server, gissrv.

Comment: It seems to just be ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll which is the problem. If I remove it the batchfile runs but not properly. I need to then add to the batch file the commands that ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll take care of, which I have had some success but not 100% there yet. I have to add source coordinate system -s_srs "EPSG:4283". It doesn't like using the existing geometry field, and if I add a new field it ends up as NULL. It looks like I need this dll.